Google Sheets: How to integrate two GOOGLEFINANCE tables horizontally using QUERY?
I have a problem that I unfortunately cannot solve on my own! I have the following formula:
=SPARKLINE(
  QUERY(
    {
      GOOGLEFINANCE(S27; "price"; R27; R27+30);
      GOOGLEFINANCE(":INX"; "price"; R27; R27+30)
    };
    "select Col1, Col2/Col4";
    1
  );
  {
    "charttype"\ "line";
    "linewidth"\ 1;
    "color"\ "#5f88cc"
  }
)

It is supposed to combine two GOOGLEFINANCE queries into one table (where S27 refers to a stock ticker, R27 refers to a date). The closing prices of both queries should then be related to each other and subsequently displayed as a SPARKLINE.
However, I am getting the error message that Col4 does not exist. I assume that QUERY integrates the two queries horizontally (so there is just Col1 & Col2). However, my function needs a vertical integration with four columns (Col1-4).
My questions are therefore:

Can I instruct QUERY to perform a horizontal integration?
Or do you see an alternative way to perform the comparative calculation of the closing prices?

Thank you very much for your ideas!
It is supposed to combine two GOOGLEFINANCE queries into one table (where S27 refers to a stock ticker, R27 refers to a date). The closing prices of both queries should then be related to each other and subsequently displayed as a SPARKLINE.

you are using non-english locale so you need to use backslash \ (not semicolon ;) to join your GOOGLEFINANCE formulae in horizontal plane:
=SPARKLINE(
  QUERY(
    {
      GOOGLEFINANCE(S27; "price"; R27; R27+30)\
      GOOGLEFINANCE(":INX"; "price"; R27; R27+30)
    };
    "select Col1, Col2/Col4";
    1
  );
  {
    "charttype"\ "line";
    "linewidth"\ 1;
    "color"\ "#5f88cc"
  }
)

see more at: Locale differences in Google Sheets (documentation missing pages)


Here's one approach to stack them side-by-side via query:
=QUERY(
    {
      GOOGLEFINANCE(S27; "price"; R27; R27+30)\
      GOOGLEFINANCE(":INX"; "price"; R27; R27+30)
    })

Alternatively you can use hstack
=hstack(
      GOOGLEFINANCE(S27; "price"; R27; R27+30);
      GOOGLEFINANCE(":INX"; "price"; R27; R27+30)
       )


Thanks! Now I combine QUERY with HSTACK which works fine for me!
